# Left join two dateframes with date columns on a range of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

Here's an example that fulfills the criteria. Dataframe df1 and df2 both have id columns and date columns. In df1 the id column is unique while in df2 it is non-unique. I'd like to create a new dataframe where the join happens if df1.id == df2.id and some pair of dates in df2 is within 1 week of the date in df1

```
df1

| customer_id (unique) | 'purchase_date'|
| --------             | -------------- |
| 1                    | 2021-05-14     |
| 2                    | 2021-09-16     |

df2

| customer_id | 'visit_dates'  |
| --------    | -------------- |
| 1           | 2021-05-11     |
| 1           | 2021-05-16     |
| 1           | 2021-05-21     |
| 2           | 2021-07-14     |
| 2           | 2021-09-17     |


# New Df will only have 1 row.
# For customer 1 there is a date within the range(05-07 -> 05-14) 
# and within the range(05-14 -> 05-21) with matching id. 
# For customer 2, there are no dates within (09-09 -> 09-16) so it should be filtered

newdf

| customer_id (unique) | 'purchase_date'| begin_date_range | end_date_range
| --------             | -------------- | ---------------- | -------------
| 1                    | 2021-05-14     | 2021-05-11       | 2021-05-16
```

I understand how to do this in SQL, but I don't know what functions allow similar date predicate filtering in Pandas.

To construct `df1` and `df2`:

```
data1 = {'customer_id': [1, 2], 'purchase_date': ['2021-05-14', '2021-09-16']}

data2 = {'customer_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
         'visit_dates': ['2021-05-11', '2021-05-16', '2021-05-21', '2021-07-14', '2021-09-17']}
```

Comment: Can you add some `df = pd.DataFrame({...})` statements that we can run to create the DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @Raymond Kwok's excellent answer: We could `merge` twice, once to left merge `df1` to `df2` and then merge the "begin_date_range" part with the "end_date_range" part

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='customer_id', how='left')
merged['purchase_date'] = pd.to_datetime(merged['purchase_date'])
merged['visit_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(merged['visit_dates'])

day_diff = merged['purchase_date'].sub(merged['visit_dates']).dt.days
out = (merged[day_diff.between(0,6)]
       .merge(merged[day_diff.between(-6,0)], on=['customer_id','purchase_date'])
       .rename(columns={'visit_dates_x': 'begin_date_range', 'visit_dates_y': 'end_date_range'}))
```

Output:

```
   customer_id purchase_date begin_date_range end_date_range
0            1    2021-05-14       2021-05-11     2021-05-16
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter the `merge` result using the week condition.

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='customer_id', how='left')
df[(df['purchase_date'] - df['visit_dates']).dt.days.between(0, 6)]
df['visit_dates+1week'] = df['visit_dates'] + pd.Timedelta(days=6)
```